# Google Charts: Uncaught Error: Row 0 has 1 columns, but must have 2

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

     function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

      [' ', 'Systol','Diastol'],
      [' ',  <?php echo "$present_sys" ?>,<?php echo "$present_dia" ?>]
    ]);
    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     [' ', 'weight'],
      [' ',  <?php echo "$present_wt" ?>]
    ]);

    var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [' ', 'SpO2'],
      [' ',  <?php echo "$pulse_rate" ?>]
    ]);
     var data4 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      [' ', 'PEF','FEV1'],
      [' ',  <?php echo "$PEF" ?>,<?php echo "$FEV1" ?>]

    ]);
```

The problem is an odd problem.. What is happening is that I choose certain types of data, the chart does work, however I choose another record, I get the following error: Uncaught Error: Row 0 has 1 columns, but must have 2. Is the reason why Google chart will work with some data and some data will not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Escape your input. Use `json_encode` to escape variables going to JavaScript, just like you would use `htmlspecialchars` to escape values going into HTML.

For certain values your script will break:

```
$bar = '"3","4"';
?>
[ '', <?php echo $bar;?> ];
<?php
```

Will give you:

```
[ '', "3", "4" ] // 3 columns!
```

If you use `json_encode`:

```
[ '', <?php echo json_encode($bar);?> ];
```

you will get:

```
[ '', "\"3\", \"4\"" ] // 2 columns
```

---

Also these two statements are functionally equivalent:

```
echo $bar;
echo "$bar";
```

`echo "$bar"` works because PHP interprets the string and finds a matching variable. This form can be quite dangerous if used accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be due to a problem with line ending characters, making PHP and/or arrayToDataTable think that there is an empty line below the header. Check/fix your data files in an editor that can explicitly show/convert line endings between Unix/Linux style (LF), Mac style (CR) and Windows style (CR LF). A situation like this may arise when the data file has been created/edited on a system with a different line ending type.

---

Source: I've had the same error message "Row 0 has 1 columns..." with a CSV file created on Excel for Mac (reading it with jquery-csv and feeding it into google viz via arrayToDataTable). When I opened the file in Excel for Windows, it showed every second line empty. Removing the empty lines and saving from Excel for Windows fixed the problem.